# Adding M365 Group to a SP Group in SPOL

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups, sharepoint-permissions

I have a number of separate M365 teams that I want to give access to a SPOL site.  I've added the various "M365 Teams Members" into the contributor group for the SPOL site, and some people appear to have access, but others don't.  Are there any settings that I have missed.
To note the teams have been customised so that the default members group on the M365 Group site was changed to a different group on the site, however that group also has the "M365 Teams Members" as its membership.

Answer (score 0):

After changing default members group of office 365 team site, remove the office 365 groups members from default members group of office 365 team site, re-add again, then have a test, compare the result.